# How do I italicize only one word in a caption?

Tags: floats, captions, italic

I need to italicize one word in a caption, but I get a `Missing $ inserted.` error. Here is my code (with dummy text):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage[backend=biber,notes,natbib,isbn=false,doi=false,url=false,eprint=false]{biblatex-chicago} 
\usepackage[main=american,vietnamese]{babel} 
\usepackage[T5]{fontenc}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes} 
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[]
  \centering
  \caption{Recreation of the original \textit{Document Name}}
  \label{fig:olddocument}
  \includegraphics[width=8cm]{example-image}\\(Source: Super Cool Archive)
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I tried `\emph` as well with no luck. If I don't use `\textit` or `\emph` everything compiles fine.

I have to italicize the name to meet styling guidelines.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please show us a complilable example (starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`) that demonstrates the issue.  Normally both `\textit` and `\emph` work in `\caption`.

Comment: does your real text involve a `_` ?

Comment: By any chance does your document title contain maths?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The text itself does not, however, the filename for the photo does.

Comment: @MarkA.Bromuela There is no maths.

Comment: The MWE I provided works, but in my document, it does not. I am using a custom document class provided by my university. Could that interfere somehow?

Comment: @DudeMcBro: What is the actual error you're getting?

Comment: @Werner This works correctly (PS I have reduced the original code) `\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,notes,natbib,isbn=false,doi=false,url=false,eprint=false]{biblatex-chicago} 
\usepackage[main=american,vietnamese]{babel} 
\usepackage[T5]{fontenc}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[]
  \centering
  \caption{Recreation of the original \textit{Document Name}}
  \label{fig:olddocument}
  \includegraphics[width=8cm]{example-image-a}\\(Source: Super Cool Archive)
\end{figure}
\end{document}`

Comment: @DudeMcBro “Could that interfere somehow?”  Yes, a lot!  `\caption` is carefully defined to _not_ break with `\textit` (and there is no reason for it to break with a `_`), but if your university template is nor careful with its redefinitions it can easily break that

Answer (score 1):

I found the fix. Once I change the filename to have no underscore in my original, everything compiles fine. I did not realize how much `caption` hates underscores.

Comment: It's probably not about captions, you'd get a missing $-error with an underscore outside a caption as well. An underscore is for making a subscript in math, but it only works in math. To actually typeset an underscore, try `\_`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Good to know.

Comment: OTOH, the caption is also written to the aux file for later use in the \listoffigures, so some formatting may need \protect.